# MySQL max_user_connections - recommended settings?

Tags: mysql

We have a good running MySQL with ~1800 queries per second.
Our max_user_connections is currently 350 and we only hit it sometimes when we deploy some experiments.

Nevertheless, it would be much more smooth if we set this to 600 to have some more air when doing bad queries manually.

Are there any drawbacks, when setting max_user_connections to a high value?
What do you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

Taken from "http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_user_connections"

max_user_connections

Permitted Values

Default 0

Range 0 .. 4294967295

The maximum number of simultaneous connections permitted to any given MySQL user account. A value of 0 (the default) means “no limit.”

So, the only drawback would be ... server may run out of resource if it's set to too high value ... depends on the server config.